# Need some advice on POCO design and Lazy<> usage for new architecture

Tags: c#-4.0, architecture, lazy-loading, poco, composition

I'm faced with an architecture decisions wich are quite tricky to solve. I'm sorry in advance for a long post but before you can help me I have to give you a context.

My company tries to integrate new architecture (based around ASP.NET MVC framework) into the existing ASP.NET legacy code. The hint is that we can't get rid of all the business code wich is encapsulated in the legacy assemblies but we have to wrap it into the new ones in order to make a sort of "anticorruption" layer and to decouple it. We're good until now, but here come one constraint (the main) that makes the decoupling a bit tricker :

1. In the legacy ASP.NET web site, they used a kind of persistance aware model in order to enable lazy loading from views (I know it's crap). There is a reason for it. The code is so convulted and difficult to deploy that they wanted to give a possibility to designers to modify only views without deploying binaries. A God class is pushed into the view with properties that are lazy loaded if needed. So for example if a designer wants to modify a view to display another property he can just pick whetever he wants from the God class and it just works. **We have to keep the same behavior in the new MVC architecture**.

Let's take an example. Let's say we have a `Item` **legacy** persistance aware DTO :

```
public class Item
{
   public string Title {get; set; }
   public List<UserComment> Comments {get; set; } // lazy loaded in the background in legacy code.
}
```

So the designer uses in the view can call a `Item.Title` and deploy and after can add if he wants `Item.Comments` (in foreach) and deploy just the view without the need of deploying all the binaries.

The following architecture has been proposed. A new POCOs for the mvc web site are located in the `Domain` assebmly which doesn't reference any other assembly. In this assembly we have also a definition of repositories interfaces like `IItemRepository`. Entities are used directly in the ASP.NET MVC ViewModels and obtained through the Repository implementations that are wired up by the underlying DI container.

We have another assebly where the implementations of IRepositories live. That assembly references all the legacy code that is used to populate the entities from the Domain.

Untill now all is great. But here's the tricky part. The entities from the domain assembly should comply with the constraint from the point 1 (lazy load in the views).

So our POCOs declare all the properties as Lazy<>. Which allows us in the implementation assembly (the one that references all the legacy code) to define delegates that populate these properties when they are accessed. Here's the new implementation of POCOs for MVC :

```
public class Item
    {
       public string Title {get; set; }
       public Lazy<List<UserComment>> Comments {get; set; } // lazy loaded in the background in legacy code.
    }
```

And here is a ItemRepository implementation :

```
public class ItemRepository : IItemRepository
{
    public Item GetItem(int id) 
    {
        Item i = new Item() { Id = id };
        i.Comments = new System.Lazy<IEnumerable<UserComments>>( () => CommentsService.GetUserComments(id));

        return i;
    }
}
```

We don't like it very much, and here's why :

- POCOs are not really POCO because it seems that there is a leaky abstraction of lifetime managment in the entities. This is not a big deal because Lazy<>, is a type in .NET Framework. On the other hand if you're using an ORM like NHibernate you have to bend your POCOs in order to allow NHibernate to load the data (sepcial constructor, virtual members, etc.)
- The other reason why we don't like it, is that it hides the underlying service composition in the repositories implementation. For example if `Item.Comments` is used, in the underlying implementation of the ItemRepository we will call to another legacy service (CommentsService.GetUserComments(id) in that case)

**Question 1 :** Do you see other drawbacks in using Lazy<> in the POCO implementation ? Or other flaws in the design that we should consider ?

**Question 2 :** How can we avoid legacy service composition in the repository implementations in order to have a clear "vision" of which
   legacy services are used ? Besides, do we really need this "vision"
   at the implementation level as we could consider repositories
   implementation as "façade" to the legacy services ?

**Question 3 :** Are there any other alternatives with a respect to the constraint 1 (lazy load) ?

**Question 4 :** Are there any guidelines related to the composition for the lazy members ?

I'm sorry for the long questions but would really appreciate your help.

Thomas

Comment: While I feel professionally qualified to offer an opinion, I personally don't feel comfortable actually doing so because the problem obviously involves a lot of moving parts and legacy issues which may combine in complex ways that I don't feel I understand well enough.

I can off one piece of advice: In a very real way you are engineering the recovery of a kind of disaster, and like any acute care, you should patch up the wounds in the best way you can while trying not to make things too much worse.

Comment: So you're basically telling us that you're hard-wiring the collapsing of your n-layer app into a single layer just for the sake of designers not having to deploy some binaries ? Sorry, I know this doesn't actually solve your problem -but I just couldn't help asking :)

Comment: @ZeroBugBounce : That's the point, we try to hide akward code, to buid up a new abstraction where and then to try keep it quite decoupled from the legacy code.

Comment: @ian31 it's not quite accurate. The legacy code is so convulted that you can't anyway build on it. Unless you accept one day of compilation et deploying for every minor change.

Comment: @Thomas I was referring to the "they used a kind of persistance aware model in order to enable lazy loading from views" part. You said it was crap but still made the conscious choice of keeping it in the new system, which surprises me.

Comment: @ian31 It's not a choice it's a constraint that I have to live with and to compose to do better. I would never made it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the lazy-loading properties have to be `List<T>`? If not, you could define them as `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>`, like this:

```
public class Item
{
   public string Title {get; set; }
   public IList<UserComment> Comments {get; set; }
}
```

Now, since the property is an instance of an interface, you could create a Virtual Proxy out of it.

Comment: Good advice Mark. I'll check it if that doesn't popup other constraints.

Comment: Mark, it's exactely the approach I've taken (if you refer to this : http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/ComposeObjectGraphsWithConfidence.aspx). I didn't know it was called a virtual proxy.